# How to make an AJAX request to another server in PhantomJS?

Tags: jquery, ajax, phantomjs, casperjs

This started out a problem using CasperJS, but it appears to be rooted in PhantomJS.  Running Phantom from command-line, how do I make an AJAX request to another server?  My test code using jQuery:

```
require("jquery.js");

$.ajax({
  url: "http://google.com",
  headers: { "Accept": "text/html" },
  success: function( data ) {
    console.log( data );
  },
  error: function( data ) {
    console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
  }

});
```

This ends up in the error block with the following:

```
{"readyState":4,"status":404,"statusText":"error"}
```

I thought I'd run into CORS problems so I run it with the --web-security=false option, but it makes no difference.  The error code is the same.  The problem is also the same as when I run it via CasperJS.

Anyone have a dirt simple example of how to do this?

Versions:

- CasperJS: 1.1.0-beta3
- PhantomJS: 1.9.7

Comment: I don't really know if there's a better way, in fact I've a related question, but what seems to work is using \__utils\__.sendAjax() casperjs method inside casper.evaluate(), so it's like an ajax call from the page to another domain, but you would still need the --web-security=no because of Cross-domain issues